# Calling server-side code from client on Derby.js

Tags: node.js, browserify, derbyjs

I'm new to using Derby.js, and have scaffolded out a project using the yeoman generator-derby package. I thought everything was going fine, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

A breakdown:

- I have an 'app/dbWp.js' controller that exports several functions, and requires the modules 'mysql', 'async', and 'needle'
- In my app/index.js, I import this file and use it like so:

  ```
      app.proto.submitWp = function() {
          dbWp.createUser(this.model);
      };
  ```
- I call this function from the view/index.jade like so:

  ```
  button.btn.btn-primary(type="button", on-click="submitWp()")
  ```
- In the browser, I get numerous console.error message complaining about the 'fs' module not being defined. After much googling, I discover that it's due to Browserify ignoring the 'fs' module, which subsequently causes problems with modules 'mysql' and 'needle'. But that implies this code is being executed in the browser?

So my question is: why is this trying to call the function on the *client* side? Obviously if it executes on the *server* side, as I thought it was going to, there wouldn't be a problem requiring these modules.

How can I execute this function on the *server*? Had this working fine with express + socket.io before, but wanted to change frameworks and give Derby.js a shot.

I'm clearly misunderstanding something about how Derby.js is supposed to work; any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is like 4 months later, but being new to DerbyJs too, I thought I could try and help.

I personally with standard html code have the equivalent working.

```
<button on-click="editContact(#contact.id)">Edit Contact</button>
```

This indeed runs code on the server. Can you try writing your code in standard HTML, or perhaps better yet, see if you can do a console.log on the server method to see if it even is getting there?

Perhaps the best would be to call an empty function on the server with a console log and check both the browser console and the server console.